# How to convert Date to days in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

So I have a problem... I have to write a programm for my college course where I count the exact number of days

so for example

the date January 1st, 0001 will be 1
and the July 26nd, 2018 will be 736412

Beneath I tried to solve this problem, but no luck. Can you point me to my mistake?

```
type Date = (Int, Int, Int)

type Year = Int
type Month = Int
type Day = Int


datetoday :: Date -> Int
datetoday (year, month , day) = day + monthtoday month + yeartoday year


yeartoday :: year -> day
yeartoday year = ((year-1)*365)


monthtoday :: month -> day
monthtoday month
     |month 1 = 0
     |month 2 = 31
     |month 3 = 59
     |month 4 = 90
     |month 5 = 120
     |month 6 = 151
     |month 7 = 181
     |month 8 = 211
     |month 9 = 243
     |month 10 = 273
     |month 11 = 304
     |month 12 = 334
```

Comment: What happened when you tried to compile this?

Comment: the compiler could not match the Type Int with month or year

Comment: yeartoday year = ((year-1)*365) this line is also wrong

Comment: Can you add the error messages you're seeing (or at least the first part of them) to your question?  This has a number of benefits -- it helps people searching for a similar question to find it, and it helps potential answerers ensure that they are talking about the same error as you are.

Comment: Your `monthtoday` doesn't take the year into account. February occasionally has 29 days, not 28.

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems with your code:

```
yeartoday :: year -> day
```

`year` and `day` should be capitalised. If you don't, this is equivalent to `a -> b`, since uncapitalised identifiers are seen as type variables. This applies to your other signatures. So, this should be:

```
yeartoday :: Year -> Day
```

And the same for the other signatures.

Here's the second problem.

```
monthtoday month
     |month 1 = 0
     |month 2 = 31
     (...)
```

The part where you write `month 1`, `month 2` etc. expects a `Bool`, so you need to compare `month` and each value, so this should be:

```
monthtoday month
     |month == 1 = 0
     |month == 2 = 31
     (...)
```

But even better, you should rewrite this as:

```
monthtoday month = case month of
    1 -> 0
    2 -> 31
    (..)
```

There are other errors to do with correctness, and there are better ways of doing this, but I'll leave this to you since the issue here is to do with the type system.